# Different ways to average an arithmetic function

Tags: number-theory, probability-distributions, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, arithmetic-functions

Consider the following ways to average a multiplicative arithmetic function $f$ over $\mathbb{N}$:

- **Arithmetic**: $\displaystyle\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N f(n)$
- **Factorized**: $\displaystyle\prod_p \left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)\sum_{v=0}^\infty \frac{f(p^v)}{p^v}$
- **Regularized**: $\displaystyle\lim_{s\to1^+}\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{f(n)}{n^s}$
- **Harmonic**: $\displaystyle\frac{1}{H_N}\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{f(n)}{n}$

Dropping the multiplicativity condition, if $f$ is an indicator function of a set $S\subseteq\mathbb{N}$  then the arithmetic and regularized averages are called the arithmetic and Dirichlet densities respectively. I believe if the arithmetic density exists then the Dirichlet one does as well and then they're equal, but not conversely.

**Question A**. Is it possible for two of these averages to exist but not be equal?

**Question B**. For which pairs of averages does the existence of one imply the existence of the other (possibly under an extra assumption on the regularity or growth of $f$)?

The hope is that there is literature on this already.

---

The factorized average is my own invention, based on the heuristic that a "random" natural number $n$ is an infinite product of powers $p^{v_p}$, where each exponent $v_p$ is random with a pdf that says the probability that $v_p=v$ is the (arithmetic) density of the set of numbers $n$ with $v_p(n)=v$, which is $(1-1/p)p^{-v}$. The probability that infinitely many $v_p$s are nonzero is $0$, and if $f$ is multiplicative we use the heuristic $\mathbb{E}(f(n))=\prod_p \mathbb{E}(f(p^v))$ based on divisibility by different primes being independent.

According to this heuristic, the probability $n$ is a specific natural is $0$ since $\prod_p(1-1/p)=1/\zeta(1)=0$, but the *ratio* between the probabilities for getting specific naturals $m$ and $n$ ought to be like the ratio $(1/m)/(1/n)$, which motivates using limiting cases of the zeta and Zipf distributions for the regularized and harmonic averages.